# BeautifulSoup and telnet not loading all div's

Tags: javascript, html, beautifulsoup, telnet

I'm building a BeautifulSoup program, and it isn't finding div's. I have confirmed with both Python code (printing) and telnet that loading the page simply doesn't load all the div's that I need.

The link is http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/scoreboard

I'm trying to capture the team and their score, but the `<div id="events" class>` isn't loading any content. When I print what is received I get `<div id="events"></div>` --> it doesn't print `class`

Is this using some sort of JS?

Comment: Yes, it's likely that the content inside the div is created via Javascript. To confirm you can use the network tab of the browser console to see what data the site is loading after the main page has loaded.  You could then **try** to make the same query that the Javascript code makes to access the score data, but your mileage will vary...

Answer (score 0):

*The events are dynamically loaded* with a separate API request and then, with the help of JS executed by the browser, the events `div` is constructed. You would need something to make this request and execute JavaScript - for instance, a real browser. Working example using headless [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) controlled by [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/scoreboard/_/date/20160313")

# waiting for at least a single event to load/appear
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#events article")))

for event in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#events article"):
    home, away = event.find_elements_by_css_selector("#teams > tr")

    home_team_name = home.find_element_by_css_selector("h2 > a[name]").text
    away_team_name = away.find_element_by_css_selector("h2 > a[name]").text

    home_score = home.find_element_by_css_selector("td.total").text
    away_score = away.find_element_by_css_selector("td.total").text

    print("'{}' against '{}'. Score: {}: {}".format(home_team_name, away_team_name, home_score, away_score))

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
'Purdue' against 'Michigan State'. Score: 62: 66
'Kentucky' against 'Texas A&M'. Score: 82: 77
```